# External Login with Microsoft Account on intune managed devices fails

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiwebview, intune, microsoft-account

We are getting this Error Title **"you can't get there from here"** in a webView used for MSA login in a Xamarin iOS app. We are using external login into a ASP.NET WebApi redirecting to the webApi itself.

The detailed error text is as follows:
**"You cannot access the resource from this browser on your device. You must use safari or intune managed browser"**

The login works for all accounts; personal and work accounts. But the accounts we have problems with, seems to be some kind of restricted work accounts.

We are using UIKit.UIWebView.

Can someone give a hint on what is going wrong here?

Is that a policy problem that can only be solved on account administration side?

Do we miss something in our app/webApi configuration?

Is there an embeddable webView control for iOS that supports that kind of account restrictions?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: It sounds like a conditional access policy has been applied to your application in the organisation's Azure AD.  You will,Ned to ask the organisation's administrators to investigate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Moving those company admins changing something is near to impossible. The same application worked for me one year before and is reused with some enhancement now after one year. Is there any workaround for this on client side? Or has there been a policy change in the meanwhile?

Comment: I doubt you can do anything on the client side; that is the point of conditional access.  You could try using `SFSafariViewController`

Comment: Is it possible to switch to OAuth authentication for your app?  Using The ADAL OAuth library gives a really nice user experience with SSO via the Microsoft Authenticator app for users in Azure AD with InTune managed devices.

Comment: Currently we are using OAuth2 with MSA (personal and company) and LinkedIn accounts. The described problem we only have with MSA.

Comment: Using `SFSafariViewController` is no option because of its restrictions in layout and data access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181524/discussion-between-paulw11-and-micha).

Comment: Hi @micha
Although this is an old thread, currently I'm experiencing the same issue with my Xamarin iOS app. Have you been able to resolve this? If so, could you please share how you were able to resolve it?